# postgresql insert inside loop is not working

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to insert some data to table based on id of product but insert with loop is not working or I did something wrong.

In short what I am trying to do is to run a loop for each id from select and insert output to pre-created table.

```
    DO $$

DECLARE
idtow int;
BEGIN
FOR idtow IN (SELECT te.tel_ilosc as ilosc,te.ttw_idtowaru as idtow FROM tg_transelem AS te LEFT OUTER JOIN tg_transakcje tr ON ((tr.tr_idtrans = te.tr_idtrans)) WHERE (te.tel_datauklienta>='2022-04-02' AND te.tel_datauklienta<='2022-04-20') AND ((te.tel_flaga&1024=0) AND (((te.tel_new2flaga>>15)&63)!=14) AND (tr.tr_rodzaj in (30,251))))

LOOP
``
INSERT INTO  zapotrzebowanie_hc (WITH base as (SELECT 
skr.idr AS fng_764972659,
skr.lpall AS Drzewo,
sk.sk_kod AS Kod,
sk.sk_idstruktury AS idtowaru,
sk.sk_nazwa AS nazwa,
skr.iloscl::float AS ilość,
sk.sk_flaga&(12) AS sk_1541782576,
twsk.tjn_idjedn AS jednostka,
sk.sk_flaga AS rodzaj,
skr.addr as addr,
skr.addrp as addrp
FROM tr_strukturakonstrukcyjna AS sk  
JOIN (WITH RECURSIVE t (id,addr,addrp,idr,idp,ilosc,iloscl,ilosc_l,ilosc_m,ilosc_s,lpall,lp) AS (SELECT idtow,'idtow'::text,''::text,'238:'||(idtow)::text,NULL::text,1::numeric,NULL::numeric,NULL::numeric,NULL::numeric,NULL::numeric,NULL::TEXT,NULL::INT  UNION SELECT r.sk_idstrukturyc,t.addr||'|'||r.sk_idstrukturyc,t.addr,'257:'||r.skr_idrelacji,t.idr,getIloscWgStruktury(r,t.ilosc,4), (r.skr_ilosc_licznik/r.skr_ilosc_mianownik), r.skr_ilosc_licznik, r.skr_ilosc_mianownik, r.skr_ilosc_skladnik, (CASE WHEN t.lpall IS NOT NULL THEN  t.lpall||'-' ELSE '' END)||r.skr_lp,  r.skr_lp FROM tr_strukturakonstrukcyjnarel AS r JOIN t ON (t.id=r.sk_idstrukturyp))SELECT * FROM t) AS skr ON (sk.sk_idstruktury=skr.id)  
LEFT OUTER JOIN tg_towary AS twsk ON ((twsk.ttw_idtowaru=sk.ttw_idtowaru)) WHERE skr.iloscl IS NOT NULL ORDER BY COALESCE(skr.addr,NULL) DESC)
SELECT (SELECT ttw_klucz from tg_towary tg JOIN tr_strukturakonstrukcyjna tr USING (ttw_idtowaru) where tr.sk_idstruktury = idtowaru) as code_of_product, SUM(mult) as zapotrzebowanie_hc
FROM (
SELECT  t.idtowaru,addr,mul((SELECT ilość FROM base b where b.idtowaru = parts::int and t.addr ilike b.addr||'%')) as mult --mul(ilość::numeric) 
from(
SELECT unnest(
  string_to_array(addr, '|')
) AS parts,idtowaru,addr FROM base ) t
GROUP BY 1,2) f
GROUP BY 1);
END LOOP;
END$$;
SELECT * from zapotrzebowanie_hc
```

It dosen't insert a thing. Tried to make it manually for specific id and works just fine.
PS. Sorry for messy code was quite in hurry.

Comment: Don't apologize for messy code, instead fix it before posting it.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I need this for tommorrow. No time :/

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Comment: Why a loop at all? This can be done with a single INSERT statement

Comment: Elaborate please. For the very first select where I look for ID's  there might be 0 ID's might be 200 ID's, and I need to run querry inside loop for every single one of them. @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it.
Problem was that in code below it dosen't matter how you name variables, it just go as count. 1 variable to 1 column in SELECT etc...

```
FOR idtow IN (SELECT te.ttw_idtowaru as idtow, te.tel_ilosc as ilosc FROM tg_transelem AS te LEFT OUTER JOIN tg_transakcje tr ON ((tr.tr_idtrans = te.tr_idtrans)) WHERE (te.tel_datauklienta>='2022-04-02' AND te.tel_datauklienta<='2022-04-20') AND ((te.tel_flaga&1024=0) AND (((te.tel_new2flaga>>15)&63)!=14) AND (tr.tr_rodzaj in (30,251))))
```

I just switched output in first SELECT also you cannot put variables inside quotes so I had to change this: `'idtow'` to this `''||idtow||''`